# How can you return a controller action to a route in Laravel 4 that is dependant on conditions?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, you assign controller actions to routes using something along the line of this:

```
Route::any('/', 'PagesController@index');
```

However, in my application I want to use a different controller and action depending on whether or not the user is logged in.

I had attempted something like this, but it does not work:

```
Route::any('/', function() {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return 'UsersController@index';
    } else {
        return 'PagesController@index';
    }
});
```

The solution I've taken to is this, but I feel there must be a proper way to achieve this, especially in instances where more than just a login-check is occurring:

```
Route::any('/', (Auth::check() ? 'UsersController@index' : 'PagesController@index'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement should be outside of the route group if you want to show a different home page for a user that is logged in.

```
if (Auth::check())
{
    Route::any('/', 'UsersController@index');
}
else
{
    Route::any('/', 'PagesController@index');
}
```

Additionally you might look at implementing some sort of authentication filter, and then redirecting non-logged in users to a different page.

Comment: Ah perfect, silly me for not seeing that. This was intended just for the homepage, so the authentication filter is used to redirect to the login page everywhere else on the site. I suppose I could write a second authentication filter just for this instance but your solution does the job perfectly.